# Why does the php script work on free hosting and on my vps it doesn't?

Tags: php, server, vps

Why does on one server error occurs 500? I don't have any ideas!

Script php:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("//strona.pl/".$_GET['url'];);
$wynik= $html->find("klasa",0) ->innertext;

print_r($wynik);
?>
```

(error 500) This script on my own vps: 
[skrypt.php](http://androidplus.ml/gen/skrypt.php)

(work corectlly) This script on free hosting: 
[androidpolska.php](http://fireandroid.zz.vc/cdagen/androidpolska.php)

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: ^^ and or at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, maybe allow-url-fopen configuration was disabled.

http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Comment: Yep. That is it. Thanks :)